# OData Function with DateTimeOffset? parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to implement an OData collection function that receives two DateTimeOffset? parameters (MinSentOn and MaxSentOn) and will return some summary information from an Orders table, but I'm having routing problems when I pass the time part of the DateTimeOffset, receiving an **HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error** directly from IIS, because it seems it's trying to reach a file and not the controller itself.

[image: Error thrown by the IIS]

This is my current OData configuration:

```
odataBuilder.Namespace = "D";
var fc =
    odataBuilder.EntityType<Order>().Collection
        .Function("ToExecutiveSummary")
        .Returns<ExecutiveSummary>();
fc.Parameter<DateTimeOffset?>("MinSentOn");
fc.Parameter<DateTimeOffset?>("MaxSentOn");
```

This is the function in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ToExecutiveSummary(DateTimeOffset? minSentOn, DateTimeOffset? maxSentOn, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return await _uow.ExecuteAndCommitAsync(async () =>
    {
        var query = _uow.Orders.Query();
        if (minSentOn != null) query = query.Where(e => e.SentOn >= minSentOn.Value);
        if (maxSentOn != null) query = query.Where(e => e.SentOn <= maxSentOn.Value);

        //  TODO    needs optimization, test only
        var executiveSummary =
            query.Select(e =>
                new ExecutiveSummary
                {
                    TotalOrders = query.Count(),
                    TotalProducts = query.Sum(ex => ex.Quantity),
                    TotalPharmacies = query.GroupBy(ex => ex.Pharmacy.Id, ex => ex.Pharmacy.Id).Count()
                }).FirstOrDefault();

        return Ok(executiveSummary);
    }, ct);
}
```

Snippet of the web.config changes to support the OData path and solve some routing problems I faced until I hit this wall, like dots or double escapes (changes have comments):

```
<configuration>

  <!--  ...     -->

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />

    <!--    Removed : and % from the path filter    -->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,&amp;,\,?"/>

    <globalization uiCulture="pt-PT" culture="pt-PT" />
  </system.web>

  <!--  ...     -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <!--  to support the dot (.) for functions or actions     -->
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>

      <!--  to support double escapings, like 2015-08-10%2000:00:00.0000%2B01:00    -->
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>

  <!--  ...     -->

</configuration>
```

Now, during my testings, I'm facing the following:

If I don't pass the time part (example: http://localhost:58806/odata/Order/D.ToExecutiveSummary(MinSentOn=null,MaxSentOn=2015-08-10) ) the request reaches my code without any problem, making me believe that there aren't any problem with the OData configuration and route.
But when I include the time part (example: http://localhost:58806/odata/Order/D.ToExecutiveSummary(MinSentOn=null,MaxSentOn=2015-08-10%2000:00:00.0000%2B01:00) ) I receive an Internal Server Error (image attached) directly from the IIS. It seems it is trying to resolve to a file instead to the controller, whence the problem.

Ultimately, I know I could receive the parameters as strings and make the parse myself, but I would like to implement this without using the "hammer" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem! It was related to the `DateTimeOffset` format I was using. I was forgetting the T, and writing `2015-08-10 00:00:00.0000%2B01:00` instead of `2015-08-10T00:00:00.0000%2B01:00` and it couldn't parse correctly.
What confused me was IIS throwing an Internal Server Error instead of some Bad Request or Not Found, and because the application exception handler wasn't being invoked, so I assumed the format was ok but IIS was having some problem with the path having unusual characters.

@Sam Xu suggestion lead me in the right path, because even using alias (I didn't know OData had support for parameter alias - thanks for that!) it was still throwing the exception...

In the end, it was a failure of mine, even if the server response should have been more enlightening...

Answer (score 4):

I do think you can use the **parameter alias** for DateTimeOffset parameter value.

For example:

http://localhost:58806/odata/Order/D.ToExecutiveSummary(MinSentOn=null,MaxSentOn=@p)?@p=2015-08-10%2000:00:00.0000%2B01:00

In the following Uri, you can find many parameter alias examples:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/UnitTest/System.Web.OData.Test/OData/Formatter/ODataFunctionTests.cs#L24-L43

Moreover, in http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support, you can find a simple guidance about function parameter.

However, the issue is a known issue related to IIS and be tracked on [odata Web APi@github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/204)

Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem! I was passing a wrong format (missing T) and the server wasn't parsing it correctly. Your suggestion lead me in the right path, because it was still failing as a query string parameter. Aside: didn't know OData supported parameter alias, big thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to a DateTimeOffset like this:

```
cast(2015-08-10%2000:00:00.0000%2B01:00,Edm.DateTimeOffset)
```

Source: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/DateAndTimeOfDay/DateAndTimeOfDayTest.cs#L181

Comment: I still get the 500, doesn't work. Sadly, the test for functions with dates does not pass the DateTimeOffset with the time, so I could try it: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/test/E2ETest/WebStack.QA.Test.OData/DateAndTimeOfDay/DateAndTimeOfDayTest.cs#L346